# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ballistic calculator for Computer science class. I can't figure out why it keeps giving the following error message :

```
travel_time = range % velocity
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting


print ("Welcome to the Laird Industries Ballistic Calculator")
range = raw_input("What is the approximate distance to your target? (m)")
velocity = raw_input("What is the muzzle velocity of the projectile? ")

def time_to_target():
    travel_time = range % velocity
    print "Travel duration {0}".format(travel_time)
#
time_to_target()
#
```

Thanks for the info. Fixed code :

```
range_to_target = raw_input("What is the approximate distance to your target? (m)")
velocity = raw_input("What is the muzzle velocity of the projectile? ")

def time_to_target():
    travel_time = float(range_to_target) / float(velocity)
    print "Travel duration {0}".format(travel_time)
#
time_to_target()
#
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `%` (the remainder operator) rather than `/` (the division operator) here?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `range` is a string (you got it from `input()`) and `%` for strings in Python is a special formatting operator.  You just need to convert to a numeric data type, something like this:

```
travel_time = float(range) % float(velocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. raw_input() returns user input as string. So your range and velocity are string and so you can not use % operator. So convert range and velocity to float.
2. range is a predefined in python. So you should not use it as variable name